# How to fetch querySelector for name containing numerics

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, queryselector

I have the below url

```
<h1 id="header_2" title="mytitle" data-id="header_title" class="sampleclass " xpath="1">mytitle<span aria-label="sometest"   class="sampleclass ">- Saved</span></h1>
```

Based in the id(header_2)I wabt to fetch title.
My id may also contains like this id="header_mdfa3fad" but for sure after "_" it is numeric.HOw do I write querySelector for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply regex to filter like this

```js
var divs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("[id^='header_']")).filter(function(el){
   return el.id.match(/^header_[0-9]+/i);
});

console.log(divs);
```

```html
<div id="header_1"></div>
<div id="header_2"></div>
<div id="header_3"></div>
<div id="header_abc"></div>
<div id="header_xyz"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

```js
const headers = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='header_']");

const titles = [];

headers.forEach((header) => titles.push(header.getAttribute('title')));

// Do something you want with titles array
```

Comment: Also you can read more about Attribute Selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I also have this format of header like header_abc0xys which I dont want. My requirement is just to fetch header_1(there is immediate numeric after _).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, try something like this:

```
#select h1 elements with id attribute whose value begins with "header"
headers = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='header_']");

#loop through the elements and extract the part of the attribute value following "_"
for (let header of headers) {
  target = header.getAttribute('id').split('_')[1]

  #check for the presence of a digit
  if (/\d/.test(target)) {
    console.log(header.getAttribute('title'))
  }
}
```